# NSTimer crashing my application

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, nsurl

So I have an application which uses an NSTimer. The problem is that when the `NSTimer` runs, my application will crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I only just started with objective-c so I don't know how to properly debug it. If I thought call the `-(void)logIn{}` with `[self logIn];` the application will work.
My code:
**.h**

```
@interface DJ_WAppDelegate : NSObject {
   NSTimer *loginTimer;
    }

    -(void)logIn;  

    @end
```

**.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self logIn];   // this works
    loginTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(logIn) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];   // this fails
}

- (void)logIn {
    NSLog(@"Logging in...");

    // if I comment out these 2 lines it works with the NSTimer!?... (I've would have more code below)
    NSURL *loginConn = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"some-website.com"]];   
    NSInteger loginReturn = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:loginConn encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil] intValue];

   // when "loginReturn" return "OK" the timer (loginTimer) will be stopped with: [loginTimer invalidate];

   // more code would be below... (which works!)
}
```

So the problem is with the NSURL it think.
 Thanks for helping.

**EDIT 1:**
Here's the crash stack:

```
    EException Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000020
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: respondsToSelector:


Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x9603bed7 objc_msgSend + 23
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x922ed5f2 _CFStringAppendFormatAndArgumentsAux + 3138
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x922ec979 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux + 105
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x9656ebfb -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 163
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x9656eaae +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 88
5   com.who.DJ-W                0x00001d56 -[DJ_WAppDelegate logIn] + 116 (DJ_WAppDelegate.m:108)
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x965b08d4 __NSFireTimer + 141
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x922ffadb __CFRunLoopRun + 8059
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x922fd464 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x922fd291 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x91646e04 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 392
11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x91646bb9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 354
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x91646a3e BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 81
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x9265378d _DPSNextEvent + 847
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x92652fce -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 156
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x92615247 -[NSApplication run] + 821
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x9260d2d9 NSApplicationMain + 574
17  com.who.DJ-W                0x00001c92 start + 54
```

hope this helps... to find the error

**EDIT 2:**
With the Zombie Mode on I get this: `*** -[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x46d550` I hope this helps.

**EDIT 3:**
To [Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426641/ball): Here is the original URL (took away the domain here) `/DJW/work.php?user=iBlackbirdi&udid=00000000-0000-1000-80005&key=660e5744e&cmd=slocau&type=get`

Comment: It would be easier to figure out what is crashing if you posted the crash stack.

Comment: When should the timer stop firing? Please [Enable NSZombie](http://cocoa-nut.de/?p=16) for your active executable and see if the console output yields something new.

Comment: I wonder if your original string for the URL included some url encoding % escapes which would confuse stringWithFormat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. `djwLog` is a class method so you should call it on the class not the instance
   like this: `[[self class] djwLog:@"foo bar"]`
2. The `URLFromString:` method needs the string to contain a valid URL as specified by [RFC 1808](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1808.txt). Something along the lines of `[NSURL URLFromString:@"http://example.com/foo"]`
3. `stringWithContentsOfURL:url…` is a syncornous method. Unless you have this code running in a separate thread you should not use this. Look at `NSURLConnection` for a class to asynchronously load data from a URL. Using synchronized calls for this is a *bad* idea. Always.
4. `intValue` returns a `signed integer`. To get a `NSInteger` use `integerValue`. Also if you use  `stringWithContentsOfURL` make sure to check if it's result is `nil` before calling 
   `integerValue` otherwise you might get a result of `0` if the URL call failed or did not return data. A real parser for the API you are calling would be a good idea in any case.

Comment: Lots of stuff I didn't know... Thanks for your reply. It was intended that if the URL call failed that the result is 0! Because the server there will return numbers only... Anyway, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling a class method as if it was an instance method:

```
[self djwLog:@"Logging in..."];
```

Since there is no instance-method named djwLog the application crashes. You should either call NSLog directly, make it an instance-method - or preferably make a macro for logging:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(...) NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
#else
#   define DLog(...) do { } while (0)
#endif
```

If you instead of NSLog write DLog - it will only be logging when DEBUG-flag has been defined. In addition to this, it will log the origin of the log message - so you can see which class/method the log entry came from.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know I can do it like that with the `NSLog()` directly. After I wrote this I noticed that the code I posted doesn't work like I did it. `[self djwLog@""]` does work. I will replace my method with `NSLog()` in my question.